# Compute homology and cohomology groups knowing homology groups with integer coefficients.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, solution-verification, group-cohomology

I'm working on this problem: Let $X$ be a space and suppose that $H_0(X;\mathbb {Z})\cong \mathbb {Z}$,
  $H_1(X;\mathbb{Z})\cong H_2(X;\mathbb {Z})\cong\mathbb {Z}\oplus\mathbb {Z}/6\mathbb {Z}$, $H_3(X;\mathbb {Z})\cong
  \mathbb {Z}$ and $H_i(X;\mathbb {Z})=0$ for $i>3$. Compute $H_i(X;\mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z})$,
  $H^i(X;\mathbb {Z})$, $H^i(X;\mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z})$ for all $i$.

The daunting thing about this kind of problem is that there is no way to check if the solution is correct or not. Here is my solution. Can you help me check it?

1. $H_i(X;\mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z}):$ By the UCT,$$
       H_i(X,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb {Z})\cong (H_i(X,\mathbb {Z})\otimes \mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z} ) \oplus Tor(H_{i-1}(X,\mathbb {Z}),\mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z}).
       $$
       Hence
       \begin{align*}
        H_0(X,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb {Z})&\cong (\mathbb {Z} \otimes \mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z} ) \oplus Tor(0,\mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z}) \cong \mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z},\\
        H_1(X,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb {Z})&\cong ((\mathbb {Z} \oplus\mathbb {Z}/6\mathbb {Z}) \otimes \mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z} ) \oplus Tor(\mathbb {Z},\mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z}) \\
        & \cong \mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z} \oplus \mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z} \oplus 0\\
        &\cong (\mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z})^2,\\
        H_2(X,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb {Z})&\cong ((\mathbb {Z} \oplus\mathbb {Z}/6\mathbb {Z}) \otimes \mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z} ) \oplus Tor(\mathbb {Z}\oplus \mathbb {Z}/6\mathbb {Z},\mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z})\\
        & \cong \mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z} \oplus \mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z} \oplus (0\oplus \mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z})\\
        &\cong (\mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z})^3,\\
        H_3(X,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb {Z})&\cong (\mathbb {Z} \otimes \mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z} ) \oplus Tor(\mathbb {Z}\oplus \mathbb {Z}/6\mathbb {Z},\mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z})\\
        & \cong \mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z}  \oplus (0\oplus \mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z})\\
        &\cong (\mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb {Z})^2,\\
        H_i(X,\mathbb{Z}/2\Z)&=0
       \end{align*}
       for $i\geq 4$.
2. $H^i(X;\mathbb {Z}):$ By the UCT,
       [
       H^i(X,\mathbb {Z})\cong Hom(H_i(X,\mathbb {Z}),\mathbb {Z})\oplus Ext(H_{i-1}(X,\mathbb {Z}),\mathbb {Z}).
       ]
       Hence
       \begin{align*}
        H^0(X,\mathbb {Z})&\cong Hom(\mathbb {Z},\mathbb {Z})\oplus Ext(0,\mathbb {Z})\\
        &\cong \mathbb {Z},\\
        H^1(X,\mathbb {Z})&\cong Hom(\mathbb {Z}\oplus \mathbb {Z}/6\mathbb {Z},\mathbb {Z})\oplus Ext(\mathbb {Z},\mathbb {Z})\\
        &\cong (\mathbb {Z}\oplus 0) \oplus 0\\
        &\cong \mathbb {Z},\\
        H^2(X,\mathbb {Z})&\cong Hom(\mathbb {Z}\oplus \mathbb {Z}/6\mathbb {Z},\mathbb {Z})\oplus Ext(\mathbb {Z} \oplus \mathbb {Z}/6\mathbb {Z},\mathbb {Z})\\
        &\cong (\mathbb {Z}\oplus 0) \oplus (0\oplus \mathbb {Z}/6\mathbb {Z})\\
        &\cong \mathbb {Z} \oplus \mathbb {Z}/6\mathbb {Z},\\
        H^3(X,\mathbb {Z})&\cong Hom(\mathbb {Z},\mathbb {Z})\oplus Ext(\mathbb {Z} \oplus \mathbb {Z}/6\mathbb {Z},\mathbb {Z})\\
        &\cong (\mathbb {Z}) \oplus (0\oplus \mathbb {Z}/6\mathbb {Z})\\
        &\cong \mathbb {Z} \oplus \mathbb {Z}/6\mathbb {Z},\\
        H^i(X,\mathbb {Z})&\cong 0
       \end{align*}
       for $i\geq 4$.

Comment: Here's a way you could 'check' the solution: Take a chain complex that has the homology you describe, tensor that with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and then take its homology, etc. By UCT the answer shouldn't depend on which complex you choose.

Comment: that's nice, thanks. Just to make sure, can you take a look above? It's been a while since I learned cohomology

Comment: I checked with this method and my H_2 is wrong, I don't know why

Comment: The simplest chain complex I think of is $Z\to Z\oplus Z_6\to Z\oplus Z_6\to Z\to 0$ where all maps are 0. But when I tensor with $Z_2$, $H_2$ should be $Z_2^2$ instead of 3 copies

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise, take a chain complex where each term is free.

Comment: oh god, I am the one who should be sorry, such a simple detail